# Open link in SharePoint modal with value from ng-grid cell value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint, ng-grid

I have filled a ng-grid with SharePoint items, I want to open the SharePoint editform in a SharePoint modal after clicking the edit button at the end of each row. 
I can only make this work without the OpenPopUpPage. When I use OpenPopUpPage the {{row.entity.Id}} does not change to the row Id and as such results in a broken edit page.

Works:

```
{ displayName: 'Edit', cellTemplate: '<a ng-href="../lists/locations/editform.aspx?IsDlg=1&id={{row.entity.Id}}">Edit</a>' }
```

Opens the modal but with broken editform (not correct id):

```
{ displayName: 'Edit', cellTemplate: '<a ng-href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenPopUpPage(\'../lists/locations/editform.aspx?IsDlg=1&id={{row.entity.Id}}\')">Edit</a>' }
```

Comment: Try ng-click instead of onclick.

Comment: <a ng-href="#" ng-click="javascript:OpenPopUpPage(\'../lists/locations/editform.aspx?IsDlg=1&id={{row.entity.Id}}\')"> - nothing happens when I click it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about sharepoint popups, but to pass a value to a function you should use this code:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
      field: 'id',
      displayName: 'Action',
      cellTemplate: '<a ng-click="popup(row.entity.id)" href="#">Edit</a>'
    }]
    };

    $scope.popup = function(id) {
    // call your popup from here
    alert(id);
    }
```

Try this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYRaaNUP4OVYInykTiHv?p=preview)